# css last-child not working as it should

Tags: css, css-selectors

In [my site](http://aqeelfikree.com), every post has a bottom border. I've applied a

`article:last-child {border-bottom:none;}`

so that the last post doesn't have a border at the bottom, but it's still showing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a more specific selector that’s applying the `border-bottom` in the first place? Like `.article-parent .article { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }`?

Comment: The last child seems to be the `div class="nav"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`last-child` will fail if you have any element other than `article` so use `last-of-type` instead.

Because the `last-child` is `nav` on your website, CSS will look for last `article` child but the last child is `nav` hence the selector goes wrong.

Where on the other hand `last-of-type` will select the last `article` element of it's parent.

Use this instead and it will work for sure

```
.content-pad-left article:last-of-type {
   border-bottom:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`last-child` is not available in [IE 8](http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child). article tag can be still solved by using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

To make backward compatible, you want to use first-child -

```
article { border-top: 1px solid #eee; }
article:first-child { border-top: none;}
```

This is what your current website look like in IE 8.

[image]

Comment: You are using windows 98 or is that a classic view? Please tell me it's a classic view

Comment: @Mr.Alien It is Window XP with IE8 running on Virtual PC 2007. It is how we test the legacy browsers in addition to browserstack.

Comment: Oh cool, will upvote your answer as I didn't specified the ie8 lacking browser support